# Proof of fundamental theorem of calculus part 1 Rudin Theorem 6.20

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, riemann-integration

I have a question about the following proof from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

> **6.20 Theorem** Let $f \in \Re$ on $[a,b]$. For $  a \leq x \leq b$, put
>
> $$F(x)  = \int_a^x f(t)dt$$ Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$; furthermore, if
> $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$  of $[a,b]$, then $F$ is
> differentiable at $x_o$ and $$F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$$
>
> (I have omitted the proof of continuity of $F$ on $[a,b]$)
>
> Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Given $\epsilon > 0 $ choose
> $\delta > 0$ such that
>
> $$\vert f(t)- f(x_o) \vert < \epsilon $$
>
> if $\vert t- x_0 \vert < \delta$, and  $a \leq t \leq b $. Hence, if
>
> $x_0 - \delta < s \leq x_0 \leq t < x_0 + \delta$ $\enspace$ with:
> $a\ \leq s < t \leq b$
>
> we have by theorem 6.12(d)
>
> $$\left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du \right| < \epsilon$$
>
> it follows that $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$

Why does Rudin use $s$ rather than $x_0$ in the epsilon portion of proving the derivative exists? If we are proving the derivative exists at $x_0$, I would expect that we would prove that

$$\left| \frac{F(t) - F(x_0)}{t-x_0} - f(x_0) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{t-x_0} \int_{x_0}^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du \right| < \epsilon$$

Comment: For $t<x_0$ you will have $\int_t^{x_0}$ and for $t >x_0$ you will have $\int_{x_0}^{t}$. So the writing become a little messy. Rudin is trying to avoid considering these twe cases separately.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you elaborate on this? Wouldn't $\int_t^{x_0}=-\int_{x_0}^t$? But we have an absolute value and I would think that this wouldn't affect anything so we could still keep the $x_0$ in there

Comment: What Kavi means (I think) is that you cannot write $\left | \int_{x_0}^t (f(u)- f(x_0))\, du \right| \le \int_{x_0}^t |f(u)- f(x_0)|\, du $ if $t < x_0$.

Comment: @MartinR Is that because the theorem is defined using the interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ and if we considered the interval $[b,a]$ with $a<b$ this would be the empty interval?

Comment: No, it is because $\int_{x_0}^t |f(u)- f(x_0)|\, du = - \int_t^{x_0} |f(u)- f(x_0)|\, du$ is *negative* if $t < x_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inequality
$$\left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| < \varepsilon$$
we have for any $s,t$ such, that $x_0-\delta \lt s \leqslant x_0 \leqslant  t \lt x_0+\delta $. So nothing prevent to take $s=x_0$ for right limit and $t=x_0$ for left limit   and obtain definition of derivative.

Comment: What is the purpose of including the $s$ at all? Is there a case when we would instead choose $t=x_0$?

Comment: Added more details to answer.